# liferay move portlets in a page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have the next requirement: every user can change position of portlet in a page but this change is only applied for this user no for all. I know that it is possible with layout and it works fine (the portlets are possible move ), but my main problem is when "x" user changes the position of a portlet  because it is applied for all users. so you have any idea for how do I this?

I work with liferay 6.2 CE

Comment: You have to use user's private pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From liferay 6.1 onwards,it provides for page customizations,where in admin can defined certain sections of the page layout as customizable allowing users to add/move/delete portlets,in specific sections.These changes will be specific to the particular user and will not be visible for others.The user has the option to anytime view the default page or to reset his customizations as well.

In order to enable this,Edit page->customization settings->Show Customizable settings and check the required sections.
Please refer the [Liferay documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/page-customizations) for further details.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem,Please accept the answer accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers